# Como alterar plugin wordpress dinamicamente?

Tags: wordpress

estou usando um plugin no `wordpress`, o qual permite que eu exiba um PDF em forma de livro.

Para usar o plugin, eu tenho que escrever a linha `[flipbook pdf="http://full-url/NOME_DO_PDF.pdf"]`

Tudo funciona perfeito. Minha dúvida é, qual o comando eu devo utilizar para que a página saiba qual arquivo PDF eu quero exibir?

Ex: eu digito na url `meusite.com/livro1.pdf` e a página entende que eu quero usar o comando `[flipbook pdf="http://full-url/livro1.pdf"]`

Espero que tenham entendido, caso minha pergunta não ficou clara, peço que comentem ou alterem antes de negativá-la.

Abraços.

Comment: Sua necessidade é transformar toda chamada de PDFs para ser chamada desse plugin?

Comment: Isso mesmo. Preciso que isso aconteça